# How to exclude a source package from jar in Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar

I have a Netbeans project where I am letting Netbeans handle the packaging; its using Netbean's build-impl.xml Ant script to package it.  There are certain packages that I do not want ending up in the final jar that Netbeans creates.  Is there a way to exclude those packages from ending up in the final jar?

In the build-impl.xml file I think this is where the Jar command is called, or at least defined.

```
<target name="-init-presetdef-jar">
    <presetdef name="jar" uri="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/1">
        <jar compress="${jar.compress}" index="${jar.index}" jarfile="${dist.jar}">
            <j2seproject1:fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" excludes="${dist.archive.excludes},**/editor/**"/>
        </jar>
    </presetdef>
</target>
```

One of the packages that I want to exclude is called "editor".  I added it in the copy above in effort to try to get it to be excluded but that didn't work, the "editor" package and all its classes still show up in the final jar.

Any ideas how I can get that package excluded from the jar?  I would rather not touch the build-impl.xml file and instead accomplish this by messing with the build.xml file which Netbeans sets aside for us to mess with... so bonus points if the solution only touches that file.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

OK I found two ways to do this (each with their own drawbacks), both from the Sources section of the Properties window.

1) Move the packages you do not want to one of your test package folders. In Properties -> Sources you can add or edit your test Package Folders.  The drawback here is that you can only use the package as a test.  This worked fine for me because the only time I had to use that code was when I was on my IDE.  It might become an issue if I ever need to add this package to a jar.

2) In Properties -> Sources at the lower right hand there is a button labeled Includes/Excludes that you can use to add files or packages to exclude for the final jar.  The drawback here is that the code is completely unusable if it relies on the other packages.  Netbeans essentially ostracizes it.  This didn't work for me.

An ideal solution would be a way to design which packages make it to the final jar then have various profiles for building these jars.  That is to say I can build Jar-A or Jar-B, each with their own packages.  I will wait for that solution before marking this question answered.

Comment: 3) Project Properties -> Build -> Packaging -> Exclude from JAR file

Comment: 4) create one project for each package you want to use separately.  Then reference those projects from the project where you need the package (Project Properties -> Libraries -> Add Project)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you provide as an answer so i can mark it as the answer

Comment: A sorry, 3) won't work because you can't exclude .class files there. So that only leaves you with moving re-usable code into a separate project

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move your packages anywhere. You can still exclude all of the `*.class` files that you don't want to include in your final JAR.

Open your `nbproject/project.properties` file and find `dist.archive.excludes` then give all of the `*.class` file name (to be excluded) as a comma-separated value to that key `dist.archive.excludes`.

Example:

```
dist.archive.excludes=`**/X*.class,**/Y*.class,**/FullClassName.class`
```

`**/X*.class`, `**/Y*.class`, X and Y are prefixes of the class, You can give the full class name as shown above

> The syntax is `**/X*.class` where X is the prefix of the class name.

Answer (score 0):

2) You can directly define all of the *.class files that has to be excluded  rather than defining the whole package from the Final jar. Go to the tag in your build-imple.xml file

`<target name="-init-presetdef-jar">
    <presetdef name="jar" uri="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/1">
        <jar compress="${jar.compress}" index="${jar.index}" jarfile="${dist.jar}">
            <j2seproject1:fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" excludes="${dist.archive.excludes},**/editor/**"/>
        </jar>
    </presetdef>
</target>`

which generates jar file. Now find the attribute excludes="${dist.archive.excludes} And EDIT this.
Example: excludes="`**/X*.class`,`**/Y*.class`,`**/FullClassName.class`"